# How to share unix domain socket between containers without named volume?

Tags: socket, containers, unix-sockets

I have two containers A and B which needs to talk via unix domain socket created by A in /var/run/notif.sock.

I can't use named volume as sharing /var/run between containers is risky as it contains container's runtime data.

Bind mount requires the host to already have a file with same name.

Problem with bind mount is if I create a host file with same name as the socket file, and use bind mount like this:
--v /var/run/notif.sock : /var/run/notif.sock , it would create a plain file /var/run/notif.sock automatically by docker inside container A and when the actual process inside container A tries to open the socket, socket file creation would fail inside the container with error "address already in use" as a file with same name is already present.

Is there any other way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

If you can configure the directory of the socket file, you could share only that directory (e.g. /var/run/share), avoiding to share /var/run.

if you cannot change the socket directory, you could try using a different socket file in A in the share directory. That new socket would be the one to which B would write (I assume from your post that A is listening to the socket and B writting), and prepare a program in A that listens to the new file and writes to the original file. The following is only a test made with socat, you should consider managing exceptions, etc.:

```
socat UNIX-LISTEN:/var/run/share/notif.sock - | socat UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/notif.sock -
```

Everything that is read from /var/run/share/notif.sock, is written in /var/run/notif.sock. Of course if you cannot change the directory in B, you could make use of a similar solution